# Publishing failing at transport

Tags: 2013, publishing, publishtransaction

Publishing is failing at transport phase and when I check publishing queue got below error:

> Could not transport xxx.zip content using https. cause unauthorized.

Kindly let me know if anyone having any solution to this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I have a few questions: 1) did it work before? 2) do you have any logs for the deployer? Which version of Tridion? It looks like something in your network (likely the deployer web application) is refusing connections.

Comment: "Unauthorized" suggests that either your credentials have changed or the required permissions have.